# wix navigation [v2] showModal with custom animation type

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I used to use wix navigation v1 for my projects, and I was able to set `animationType` within my showModal function :

`this.props.navigator.showModal(
  screen: 'example.ModalScreen',
  animationType: 'none'
)`

but in wix v2, there is no way to do so. default animation type for me is slide-up, and I don't want that. I tried setDefaultOptions with the following opitons:

```
        animations: {
            showModal: {
                alpha: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 1,
                    duration: 5,
                    startDelay: 0,
                },
                y: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 0,
                    duration: 5,
                    startDelay: 0,
                }
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work at all.